# Google Spreadsheet conditional formatting for 2 columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, multiple-conditions, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to have custom formula for conditional formatting, but it doesnt seem to work with the 2 conditions...:

```
Columns TS Time

Row1    Y   80

Row2    N   85

Row3    Y   60

Row4    N   4
```

**Column 'Time' --> Should be**

```
Red if Time >= 80 and TS = 'N'  

Orange if Time >= 80 and TS = 'Y'

Yellow if Time< 80 and Time > 24 --> This works

Green if Time <= 24  --> This works
```

Comment: What have you done about this?

Comment: Did you use the =AND( ) statement? There is some information about conditional formatting in this SO question that might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905600/conditional-formatting-with-custom-formula-referencing-the-cell-itself, but I'm not sure what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: I tried AND condition highlighted below but it doesnt work by applying to the range of choice with the required colors :
    
    AND(C25 ='N', D25>= 80) =TRUE() 
    AND(C25 ='Y', D25>= 80) =TRUE()
 > C25 has column TS data value and D25 has time. I would like to have this not being specific to the cell vs. column itself but that doesnt work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the conditional formatting, set the range to be applied to for the column you want highlighted, choose custom formula and add each one of these as it's own rule:

For orange:

```
=if(and(C:C>=80,B:B=""Y""),true,false)
```

and for red:

```
=if(and(C:C>=80,B:B=""N""),true,false)
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked.  Can you please accept the answer when you have a moment.  Thanks!